# Netlogo Plot Histogram Percentage

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a histogram in NetLogo that shows percentage instead of frequency for each unique value in a list. Let's say we have a list `[1 1 2 5]` so the histogram should have 3 bars corresponding to below points:

```
Bar1-->(x:1, y:0.5)
Bar2-->(x:2, y:0.25)
Bar3-->(x:5, y:0.25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the barplot, I think the easiest way might be to make use of the `plotxy` function in NetLogo. With this setup:

```
globals [ example_list ]

to setup
  ca
  set example_list [ 1 1 2 5 ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

A `to-report` to get the frequency of items in a list:

```
to-report freq [ i_ list_ ]
  report length filter [ ind -> ind = i_ ] list_
end
```

And then a `to-report` to find the proportion for each unique value passed and output that value paired with the unique value (more details in comments):

```
to-report freq_map [ list_ ]
  ; get length of input list
  let len length list_

  ; get unique values for the input list
  let uniques remove-duplicates list_

  ; get counts of each unique value
  let counts map [ i -> freq i list_ ] uniques

  ; report an xy pair for each unique value / proportion
  report ( map [ [ x y ] -> list x ( y / len ) ] uniques counts )
end
```

Now, you can pass a list to `freq_map` and it will output a list of lists of xy pairs:

```
observer> show freq_map [ 1 1 2 5 ]
observer: [[1 0.5] [2 0.25] [5 0.25]]
```

You can now set up your plot. If you use `foreach` to `plotxy` for each one of those pairs, like so:

[image]

Your plot will look something like this, so long as you scale it properly with your `X max` and `Y max` settings:

[image]